# Shared Folder is not working for host Ubuntu 14.04 and virtual box 4.3.16

Tags: virtualbox, shared-folders

I have installed Virtualbox 4.3.16 on Ubuntu 14.04 host system. The guest operating system is Win XP. I have installed Guest Addition CD and added a shared folder through settings. For sometime it shown the folder on Network Places and there after, on clicking the icon of the same, it shows an error.

Sometimes i got access just by installing guest Addition CD again, but later on restarting the guest system it gives the same error as "Disk is not accessible. The parameter is incorrect."

Comment: I had that error because my shared partition wasn't mounted on the host. :(

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this with a Windows 7 guest on Linux Mint Cinnamon 17, possibly due to a Windows upgrade. If you manually disconnect the disk volumes in the Windows File Explorer (right-click, then Disconnect) and then power off the guest OS and restart, it may fix the problem.